# How to initialze an appium android driver on version 4.0.0 with selenium 3.141.0

Tags: c#, android, selenium, testing, appium

I can't find any documentation outlining how to initialize an appium android driver.

I had this test somewhat working with appium `3.0.0.2` and selenium `3.11` but then received the following error when trying to find an element by class name:

> OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException: 'Locator Strategy 'css selector' is not supported for this session

Ideally I don't want to go back to an older version of selenium as I already have a set of working tests using `3.14`. This is my test at the moment, and I cant find clear documentation telling me how to implement an appium driver in `C#`.

```
  public void androidTest(){
      AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;
      DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
      cap.SetCapability("deviceName", "myName");
      cap.SetCapability("platformName", "Android");
      cap.SetCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
      cap.SetCapability("appPackage", "myPackage");
      cap.SetCapability("appActivity", "myActivity");

      Uri url = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");

      driver = new AndroidDriver<IWebElement>(url, cap);

      driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

      driver.FindElementByName("android.widget.EditText").SendKeys("testString");
   }
```

I get the following two error messages

Argument 1:

> cannot convert from `'System.Uri'` to `'OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.ICommandExecutor'`

Argument 2:

> cannot convert from `'OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DesiredCapabilities'` to `'OpenQA.Selenium.DriverOptions'`    ArenaTests

What arguments do I need to pass into this constructor to get this setup working?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I worked this out. If anyone runs into this, the following initialisation works for me.

```
public void androidTest(){
    AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;
    AppiumOptions options = new AppiumOptions();
    options.PlatformName = "Android";
    options.AddAdditionalCapability("deviceName", "MyDevice");
    options.AddAdditionalCapability("platformVersion", "PlatformV");
    options.AddAdditionalCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
    options.AddAdditionalCapability("appPackage", "MyPackage");
    options.AddAdditionalCapability("appActivity", "MyActivity");

    Uri url = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");

    driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(url, options);
    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

    // Some example selectors
    driver.FindElementByClassName("android.widget.EditText").SendKeys("test");
    driver.FindElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().className(\"android.widget.EditText\").instance(1)")).SendKeys(Username);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks h brooker you helped me alot

for UWP users:

```
AppiumOptions options = new AppiumOptions();
            options.PlatformName = "UWP";
            options.AddAdditionalCapability("deviceName", "WindowsPC");
            options.AddAdditionalCapability("app", AppId);
session = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new 
                Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), options);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the URI is creating an issue ..
Try using URL like the following snippet..

```
        URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");

        driver = new AppiumDriver<MobileElement>(url,cap);
```